# Can somebody post a good example of MVC Pattern in Swift?

Tags: swift, model-view-controller

A simple project which has implemented the MVC pattern. So far,I have a brief understanding of how it is like but I want to see the practical implementation.

Comment: Don't you think few of the Samples from Apple are MVC patterns https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code

Comment: But they are in objective c

Comment: @Isha check  following link its about UISearchController https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html It has both objective c as well as swift example

Comment: Visit download page of any link from apple sample code. Those which are translated in swift have description "Including Swift project. "

Comment: Thanks Will do that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a typical example of Model View Controller in swift:

```
class Article {
  var title: String
  var body: String
  var date: NSDate
  var thumbnail: NSURL
  var saved: Bool
}

class ArticleViewController: UIViewController {
  var bodyTextView: UITextView
  var titleLabel: UILabel
  var dateLabel: UILabel

  var article: Article {
    didSet {
      titleLabel.text = article.title
      bodyTextView.text = article.body

      let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
      dateLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(article.date)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the Controller Class/Layer here?

Comment: ArticleViewController is the Controller : manages the view and speaks with the model.

Comment: okay, then where is the VIEW Layer?
is it the bodyTextView, titleLabel and dateLabel?

if yes, why is it that they are not separated with the Controller Layer?

Comment: The MVC design pattern have three types of objects: model objects, view objects, and controller objects: each of the three types of objects is separated from the others by **abstract** boundaries ( and communicates with objects of the other types across those boundaries). Classic 
design could be misleading to think of doing a physical separation of the elements, but it is not mandatory.

Comment: If you need more details about it you can take a look to the official docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14)

Comment: thank you for answering me and pointing me to the documentations :) I felt like there's more to learn! :D